# How to create duplicate for default opencart contact us form with additional fields

Tags: php, opencart

In my opencart template i need to create a form which is similar to contact form with the fields Name,Email and Mobile number.I have already used the default contact us form in my contact us page.I need to create this new form for another page.Is there any free extension available?Or else how can we implement our own form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not going to recommend any extension (this is not the place to do so) but i can tell you some steps duplicate the contact from.

First you need to duplicate three files in their respective directories

1. `catalog\language\english\information\contact.php`
2. `catalog\view\theme\default\template\information\contact.tpl`
3. `catalog\controller\information\contact.php`

and name them `form.php`,`form.tpl`,`form.php`

All changes after this point will be performed on these files only

now change you controller class name to `ControllerInformationForm`
other than this you will have to edit several things in controller file like change `contact.tpl` to `form.tpl` , load correct language file using `$this->language->load('information/form');`

after making necessary changes to controller file, your new form can be accessed using `website.com/index.php?route=information/form`

now for additional field take one existing field like `name` and do all things which are done for `name` in these 3 files with your new field

**Note** don't do `$mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);` for you new field its different

now lets in tpl you have new field in tpl like this

```
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
```

then in your controller change following line

```
$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

to

```
$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'] . " " . $this->request->post['city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

**Disclaimer** : This not a full set of instruction but this is enough for you to start and to ask better question if you face any problem

Comment: Hi is it possible to send mail to admin after submit this duplicate form.Whether i have to add any new code for send email to admin?@Chetan Paliwal

Comment: @user3489161 all contact form does is send mail to admin, so yes it will send the mail,that code is already there in controller file

Comment: Thanks alot.Its working fine.But if i need to send all the details such as name,Email,and enquiry message in mail means how i have to update the below code?                                                                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
     $mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))); @Chetan Paliwal

Comment: `$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'] . "\n" . $this->request->post['email']. "\n" . $this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));`

Comment: Hi if i need to get the output along with the label text like Name:XXXX , Email:YYY. how we can get it?@Chetan Paliwal

Comment: @user3489161 anything you will put inside `$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode()))` will get printed in mail. so just google the way you want. learn about string concatenation in php etc i present a example before you which clrealy shows how text is printed in mail and how to print multiple variables, you just have to put your labels between them, i can't tell you everything like how to print a comma or how to print a full stop you will have to learn these little things