# Opencart assign contact form to other pages

Tags: php, forms, opencart, contacts

In total I have 3 pages with forms in my OpenCart installation. The first page is contact form which is by default. Second page is stockiest which will have same fields as contact form and third form will have a additional image upload field.

Problem is, if I assign contact layout to stockiest page, it shows nothing. Similarly, I don't know how to add image field and mail it to admin. There are some extensions. But they replace contact form.

I have gone through this thread: [How to create duplicate for default opencart contact us form with additional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810368/how-to-create-duplicate-for-default-opencart-contact-us-form-with-additional-fie) 
But it is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is probably not sufficiently specific for us to help, I wonder. Can you add some screenshots of the problem? If you are brand new to OpenCart development, you may wish to do some tutorials to familiarise yourself with the product, or even take on a freelancer from the OpenCart community to help with getting started.

Comment: thanks for your reply @halfer. when i assign contact layout to stockiest page, it shows only heading of page and form is not showing.similarly, when i found thread mentioned above,i copied files,changed controller name,added route as specified in thread.still it shows only heading and not the form.