# OPENCART: Use Duplicate of Contact Form in Another Page Not Working

Tags: php, opencart, contact-form, opencart2.x

I followed the tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810368/how-to-create-duplicate-for-default-opencart-contact-us-form-with-additional-fie) on how to create a duplicate contact form. I created the 3 files needed. This is working as expected when I go to the url `information/form`. However, I can't make it work when I want it to be included in another page. I added it in the information page and just call it when the page I needed it to appear is clicked/called.

First off, I removed the header and footer inclusions in the `.tpl` file because it's already in the parent page. Then I called `$this->load->controller('information/form')` in the catalog controller where I want it to appear but it's not working. I used `$this->load->view('information)` and it works but the functionalities are not there (which is obvious because it's only calling for the view).

My current code in `catalog/controller/information/information`:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->language('information/information');
    $this->load->language('information/form');

    $this->load->model('catalog/information');

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
    );

    $information_id = 0;

    if (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
        $information_id = (int)$this->request->get['information_id'];
    }

    $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($information_id);

    if ($information_info) {
        
        $this->document->setTitle($information_info['meta_title']);
        $this->document->setDescription($information_info['meta_description']);
        $this->document->setKeywords($information_info['meta_keyword']);

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $information_info['title'],
            'href' => $this->url->link('information/information', 'information_id=' .  $information_id)
        );

        $data['heading_title'] = $information_info['title'];

        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($information_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $contact_data['text_location'] = $this->language->get('text_location');
        $contact_data['text_store'] = $this->language->get('text_store');
        $contact_data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact');
        $contact_data['text_address'] = $this->language->get('text_address');
        $contact_data['text_telephone'] = $this->language->get('text_telephone');
        $contact_data['text_fax'] = $this->language->get('text_fax');
        $contact_data['text_open'] = $this->language->get('text_open');
        $contact_data['text_comment'] = $this->language->get('text_comment');
        $contact_data['text_contact_info'] = $this->language->get('text_contact_info');
        $contact_data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
        $contact_data['error_name'] = '';
        $contact_data['name'] = '';
        $contact_data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
        $contact_data['error_email'] = '';
        $contact_data['email'] = '';
        $contact_data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
        $contact_data['error_telephone'] = '';
        $contact_data['telephone'] = '';
        $contact_data['entry_subject'] = $this->language->get('entry_subject');
        $contact_data['error_subject'] = '';
        $contact_data['subject'] = '';
        $contact_data['entry_enquiry'] = $this->language->get('entry_enquiry');
        $contact_data['error_enquiry'] = '';
        $contact_data['enquiry'] = '';
        $contact_data['captcha'] = '';
        $contact_data['button_submit'] = 'SUBMIT';
        $contact_data['action'] = $this->url->link('information/form');
        /*THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE CUSTOM CONTACT FORM VIEW*/
        $data['contact'] = $this->load->view('information/form', $contact_data); //$this->load->controller('information/form');
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('information/information', $data));
    }
}
```

Is it achievable? Or do I really need to double everything?

Comment: what is actually need?

Comment: please upload here all 3 files like controller, view, and language files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tell you some steps to duplicate the contact form.

First, you need to create 3 files in their Information directories.

**Note:** Please Give a Proper Filename like form or etc if you want.

> **1. catalog\controller\information\form.php**

```
<?php
class ControllerInformationForm extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('information/form');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
            $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
            $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
            $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

            $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
            $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setText($this->request->post['enquiry']);
            $mail->send();

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/form/success'));
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('information/form')
        );

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_location'] = $this->language->get('text_location');
        $data['text_store'] = $this->language->get('text_store');
        $data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact');
        $data['text_address'] = $this->language->get('text_address');
        $data['text_telephone'] = $this->language->get('text_telephone');
        $data['text_fax'] = $this->language->get('text_fax');
        $data['text_open'] = $this->language->get('text_open');
        $data['text_comment'] = $this->language->get('text_comment');

        $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
        $data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
        $data['entry_enquiry'] = $this->language->get('entry_enquiry');

        $data['button_map'] = $this->language->get('button_map');

        if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
            $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
        } else {
            $data['error_name'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['email'])) {
            $data['error_email'] = $this->error['email'];
        } else {
            $data['error_email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['enquiry'])) {
            $data['error_enquiry'] = $this->error['enquiry'];
        } else {
            $data['error_enquiry'] = '';
        }

        $data['button_submit'] = $this->language->get('button_submit');

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('information/form', '', true);

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if ($this->config->get('config_image')) {
            $data['image'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->config->get('config_image'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_location_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_location_height'));
        } else {
            $data['image'] = false;
        }

        $data['store'] = $this->config->get('config_name');
        $data['address'] = nl2br($this->config->get('config_address'));
        $data['geocode'] = $this->config->get('config_geocode');
        $data['geocode_hl'] = $this->config->get('config_language');
        $data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');
        $data['fax'] = $this->config->get('config_fax');
        $data['open'] = nl2br($this->config->get('config_open'));
        $data['comment'] = $this->config->get('config_comment');

        $data['locations'] = array();

        $this->load->model('localisation/location');

        foreach((array)$this->config->get('config_location') as $location_id) {
            $location_info = $this->model_localisation_location->getLocation($location_id);

            if ($location_info) {
                if ($location_info['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($location_info['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_location_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_location_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = false;
                }

                $data['locations'][] = array(
                    'location_id' => $location_info['location_id'],
                    'name'        => $location_info['name'],
                    'address'     => nl2br($location_info['address']),
                    'geocode'     => $location_info['geocode'],
                    'telephone'   => $location_info['telephone'],
                    'fax'         => $location_info['fax'],
                    'image'       => $image,
                    'open'        => nl2br($location_info['open']),
                    'comment'     => $location_info['comment']
                );
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
            $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
        } else {
            $data['name'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
        } else {
            $data['email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['enquiry'])) {
            $data['enquiry'] = $this->request->post['enquiry'];
        } else {
            $data['enquiry'] = '';
        }

        // Captcha
        if ($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('contact', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
            $data['captcha'] = $this->load->controller('extension/captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha'), $this->error);
        } else {
            $data['captcha'] = '';
        }

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('information/form', $data));
    }

    protected function validate() {
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 32)) {
            $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }

        if (!filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['enquiry']) < 10) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['enquiry']) > 3000)) {
            $this->error['enquiry'] = $this->language->get('error_enquiry');
        }

        // Captcha
        if ($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('contact', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
            $captcha = $this->load->controller('extension/captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha') . '/validate');

            if ($captcha) {
                $this->error['captcha'] = $captcha;
            }
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }

    public function success() {
        $this->load->language('information/form');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('information/form')
        );

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_message'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/success', $data));
    }
}
```

**2. catalog\view\theme\default\template\information\form.tpl**

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <h3><?php echo $text_location; ?></h3>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <?php if ($image) { ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $store; ?>" title="<?php echo $store; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><strong><?php echo $store; ?></strong><br />
              <address>
              <?php echo $address; ?>
              </address>
              <?php if ($geocode) { ?>
              <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo urlencode($geocode); ?>&hl=<?php echo $geocode_hl; ?>&t=m&z=15" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php echo $button_map; ?></a>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><strong><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></strong><br>
              <?php echo $telephone; ?><br />
              <br />
              <?php if ($fax) { ?>
              <strong><?php echo $text_fax; ?></strong><br>
              <?php echo $fax; ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <?php if ($open) { ?>
              <strong><?php echo $text_open; ?></strong><br />
              <?php echo $open; ?><br />
              <br />
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($comment) { ?>
              <strong><?php echo $text_comment; ?></strong><br />
              <?php echo $comment; ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php if ($locations) { ?>
      <h3><?php echo $text_store; ?></h3>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <?php foreach ($locations as $location) { ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse-location<?php echo $location['location_id']; ?>" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"><?php echo $location['name']; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-location<?php echo $location['location_id']; ?>">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <?php if ($location['image']) { ?>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><img src="<?php echo $location['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $location['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $location['name']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><strong><?php echo $location['name']; ?></strong><br />
                  <address>
                  <?php echo $location['address']; ?>
                  </address>
                  <?php if ($location['geocode']) { ?>
                  <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo urlencode($location['geocode']); ?>&hl=<?php echo $geocode_hl; ?>&t=m&z=15" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php echo $button_map; ?></a>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"> <strong><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></strong><br>
                  <?php echo $location['telephone']; ?><br />
                  <br />
                  <?php if ($location['fax']) { ?>
                  <strong><?php echo $text_fax; ?></strong><br>
                  <?php echo $location['fax']; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <?php if ($location['open']) { ?>
                  <strong><?php echo $text_open; ?></strong><br />
                  <?php echo $location['open']; ?><br />
                  <br />
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if ($location['comment']) { ?>
                  <strong><?php echo $text_comment; ?></strong><br />
                  <?php echo $location['comment']; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <legend><?php echo $text_contact; ?></legend>
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_email; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-enquiry"><?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea name="enquiry" rows="10" id="input-enquiry" class="form-control"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>
              <?php if ($error_enquiry) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_enquiry; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php echo $captcha; ?>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_submit; ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

**3. catalog\language\en-gb\information\form.php**

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']  = 'Contact Us';

// Text
$_['text_location']  = 'Our Location';
$_['text_store']     = 'Our Stores';
$_['text_contact']   = 'Contact Form';
$_['text_address']   = 'Address';
$_['text_telephone'] = 'Telephone';
$_['text_fax']       = 'Fax';
$_['text_open']      = 'Opening Times';
$_['text_comment']   = 'Comments';
$_['text_success']   = '<p>Your enquiry has been successfully sent to the store owner!</p>';

// Entry
$_['entry_name']     = 'Your Name';
$_['entry_email']    = 'E-Mail Address';
$_['entry_enquiry']  = 'Enquiry';

// Email
$_['email_subject']  = 'Enquiry %s';

// Errors
$_['error_name']     = 'Name must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
$_['error_email']    = 'E-Mail Address does not appear to be valid!';
$_['error_enquiry']  = 'Enquiry must be between 10 and 3000 characters!';
```